# SwiftUI edgesIgnoringSafeArea in List

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to add a `List view` with a `header view`, that is ignoring `top safe area inset`. But for some reason `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` doesn't work with `List`

```
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List {
                rankingHeader(geometry: geometry)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .animation(.none) 

                ForEach(viewModel.entries, id: \.self) { string in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? The same code works when working with other views than `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, actually you need to set edges according to GeometryReader, not list:

```
   GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            rankingHeader(geometry: geometry)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .animation(.none)
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.entries, id: \.self) { string in
                    Text(string)
                }
            }
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me, because I need the rankingHeader to scroll with the list, not stay on top. And if I put it inside the list, then it is adjusted to top safe area, which Im trying to avoid.

Comment: Doesn't work https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/03o5-x0VMEyvpAE78DO4IUMpg#Zrzut_ekranu_2020-07-9_o_14.04

Comment: now I see, try set edgesIgnoringSafeArea, where you try to call this RankingView

Comment: I tried adding this to every view added, but it just doesn't work with List for some reason. Only for List; works for other containers

Comment: https://cvws.icloud-content.com/B/ASW1sPcf8f70L9L33n5yIG2XH-ghAeezXD9IJBBbjy3sAKBGIvxr-u6z/Screenshot+2020-07-09+at+14.16.37.png?o=ApNles1h7ZQR6GDyTPpn5EREgDOcWOQI38Z6k74OHAjz&v=1&x=3&a=CAogvYiUVUcmK83Roc5wJGaCNcVYnJol3lnt2nxj12dgl5USbRCPsI2csy4Yr6fEnLMuIgEAUgSXH-ghWgRr-u6zaiboui4UpbX-Cc3pjdrz4Tp8PwQSfellPW-yye3fwQ7sCrHzrERGUHIm2E8aJYLmzQPfG5mEKUYaYV7ACpX6h4-Uytp1tVpa9fraX295dc0&e=1594298012&fl=&r=751a48c9-84e4-448d-9755-51685c0185f8-1&k=YHVGUdJph9uWQFMLjUOdVw&ckc=com.apple.clouddocs&ckz=com.apple.CloudDocs&p=56&s=LSEUMa6QW1TGvZxEaA60p0G4DA8&cd=i.

Comment: Seems to be you have problem inside your header, maybe you have some padding inside.

Comment: OK, looks like this is XCode 12 Beta issue only. Works in Xcode 11. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Damian, Can you post the code for RankingHeader and viewModel as its difficult to work out your intent from the code posted.  However, you are using List but also using ForEach.  You shouldn't need both as List takes an itterable list.  Try something like this which uses Navigation view to provide the Header:

```
var body: some View {
 
    NavigationView {
        GeometryReader {proxy in
            List(0..<4) { index in
                Text("hello \(index)")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Events", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button("Print Proxy") {
                    print("proxy: \(proxy.size)")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore the safe areas then you can add edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) to the navigation bar modifiers but this makes the list start underneath the header which is not likely to be what you want.

Comment: For now, I'm just using LazyVStack with custom views for rows, as this interface is highly customized anyway and doesn't contain too many rows. I marked this as TODO to check in the next beta releases. I'll try to find a similar issue, and if I can't find it, I'll create an issue.